# PHP opendir on smb mounted server

Tags: php, macos, xampp, smb, opendir

I am trying to `opendir` on a SMB mounted server. I'm running XAMPP on a Mac. I keep getting "No such file or directory" but i can `cd` to the directory just fine from terminal using the same path.

```
$dir = opendir("/Volumes/photorepos/Partners");

echo $dir;
```

Comment: you are going outside your document root defined for the server so it is correct. Probably you can try with a symlink to that path and to try to refer to the symlink. Anyway take also into account user permissions on the files you are trying to open

Comment: I have full permissions to that directory, so it shoudln't be an issue to get to it. I'm trying to get to the directory to count files, so i don't think symlink will work since the next step after i open the directory will be to glob the files in it. right?

Comment: the webserver user must have at least read permission on the directory and the directory must be inside the document root.

Comment: Your webserver probably runs as user `_www` and group `_www` so that user needs access, not you. Check your Apache config file for the `User`.